# What is the difference between malloc and (object*)malloc?

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn about casts and how they work. I have this

(Defined in the Header file)

```
typedef struct {
    int code;
    char* name;
    float concentration;
    int quantity;
} Farmacy;
```

In the .c file when I'm creating a new object when should I use:

```
Farmacy* f= malloc(sizeof(Farmacy));
```

or

```
Farmacy* f= (Farmacy*)malloc(sizeof(Farmacy));
```

Comment: Neither, use `Farmacy* f = malloc(sizeof  *f);`